# hard time to fix the height for a div with dinamic content

Tags: html, css

Here's my code:

```
<div class="scroll">
   <div class="category>
       <h1>Title</h1>
       <ul><li>...</li>
           <li>...</li>
           ...</ul>
   </div>
   <div class="category>
       <h1>Title</h1>
       <ul><li>...</li>
           <li>...</li>
           ...</ul>
   </div>
   <div class="category>
       <h1>Title</h1>
       <ul><li>...</li>
           <li>...</li>
           ...</ul>
   </div>
```

The div scroll has absolute position, the divs "category" have relative position and height: fit-content, the `<ul>` have absolute position and height: fit-content.

The content of the `<ul>` is dinamic (I get it from a database)

When I load the page the `<ul>` has height=0 and so all the div "category" are overlapping.

Here's the css:

```
.scroll {
    bottom:0px;
    left:100%;
    width: 100%;    
    position:absolute;
    opacity:0;
    overflow-x:hidden;  
    top: -20px;
}

.scroll ul {
    height: fit-content;
    position: absolute;
    top:30px;
    width:85%;
    left:15%;
    opacity:1;
    bottom:30px;
    right:5%;
    font-family:'Amatic SC', 'Open Sans', Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-align:center;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 30px;
}

.scroll li {
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    margin-bottom: 65px;
    width:40%;
    margin-right: 10%;  
}
.category {
    position: relative;
    height: fit-content;
}
```

Any suggestion? Thanks
I hope I was clear enough

Comment: Not sure what MySQL has to do with it? "The content of the <ul> is dinamic (I get it from a database)." then you could also post your server side code which generates this html..

Comment: post the css styles.

Comment: @RaymondNijland you are right, mysql has nothing to do with it. I think there's no need to post the code that generates the html, I'm sure it works fine because I'm already using it elsewhere

Comment: @MadhawaPriyashantha, done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it! I removed "position:absolute" from .scroll ul and "float:left" from .scroll li

Comment: Please accept your own answer, so people can see easily that you already got a solution.